# Looking for a specific operations research software

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, solver, software

I would like to ask for help to identify the research operational software that is being used in the picture
[image]

I think it looks nice and I'd like to use it (It doesn't seem to be Lingo nor Excel Solver).

Comment: If an answer has answered your question, you can upvote and click the 'accept answer' button. That way, other people that see your question can see that the question comes with an answer that adequately addressed the question.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like QM for windows. I'm not sure whether this software is still maintained.